# In-house code used in paper methods section but not shared

Tags: research-process, advisor, data, code

I am muddling my way through my program an stumbled upon a technique I would really want to employ in my research. The technique is well outside the realm of my PI's expertise and my PI would not run in the same circle as the person whose paper I want to leverage.

I have access to the necessary equipment through a core on campus, but I would need some support to establish a foothold in this subject matter. I have been reading some additional papers from the lab, but some of the finer details are probably housed in the code (matlab scripts).

I wanted to start by recreating what was in the published paper but the in-house code is not provided. That raw data is though. Is that common?

I sent a note asking for the code following the guidance of another post on this site. A complicating factor is the PI is a leader in the field (big lab, Nature papers etc...) and I am in a brand new lab.

Hopefully I hear back, but shouldn't you have to release the code necessary to create the figures?

I am in the biomedical field.

Comment: Is it just the code that creates the figures in the paper or the code that established the results? I doubt that it is necessary to release the former.

Comment: You may be interested in this closely related question: [Why are papers without code but with results accepted?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/23237/17254), as well as [Can I request the code behind a research paper from the author?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/26162/17254).

Comment: It is in the field of imaging and spectral analysis. Front my garage point the scripts are necessary for bit the images and any interpretation.

Comment: @TheCodeNovice "Front my garage point"? Is that supposed to be "from my vantage point"?

Comment: @Anyon Yes, and sorry my phones auto correct is pretty vicious. I should of waited and commented from my laptop. And I saw those related post, but they were CS related and I figured a code heavy discipline such as that may have different rules of etiquette vs other STEM fields.